# DELAYED_JOB Update_attribute in delayed job is not working, table not updated

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, update-attributes, update-attribute

I has been wanted to do the Delayed::Job which to do the fbLikes ( I post a lot on StackOverFlow but still haven't solve the problem yet) My table n database have name, id, fbLikes, fbId, url.
Here is my steps for the program.
[Home Page]company list -> Create a Company[Insert A company infos] ->Save fbId, name, id, url BUT NOT FBLIKES -> redirect to HomePage [after_save Update the fbLikes for the previous added company]

I not sure whether my delayed job is working or not because my fbLikes in my model is still blank and not updated with latest fbLikes.I not sure is there a better way to do this.
For "rake jobs:work" there is no background work display in the console.

[MODEL company.rb]

```
require "delayed_job"
require "count_job.rb"
after_save :fb_likes
def fb_likes    
    Delayed::Job.enqueue(CountJob.new(self.id))
end
```

[lib/count_job.rb]

```
require 'net/http'
require 'company.rb'

class CountJob < Struct.new(:id)        
  def perform
    @company = Company.find(id)
    uri = URI("http://graph.facebook.com/#{@company.fbId}")
    data = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    @company.fbLikes= JSON.parse(data)['likes']
    @company.save!
  end
end
```

Comment: A few things I notice is that you used CountJob.new(@count) but your CountJob class does not define any initializers. Are you not getting an exception? Also, what happens if another company gets created before the delayed_job is run? Maybe you should pass the id to the CountJob and enqueue it in the create method.

Comment: I tried a lot of ways to do this(whether pass value or not or Delayed Job in Model or in page controller) but still no avail.

Comment: Check your database if the job gets created and if it has any last_error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MODEL company.rb]

```
require "delayed_job"
require "count_job.rb"
after_save :fb_likes
def fb_likes    
    Delayed::Job.enqueue(CountJob.new(self.id))
end
```

[lib/count_job.rb]

```
require 'net/http'
require 'company.rb'

class CountJob < Struct.new(:id)        
  def perform
    @company = Company.find(id)
    uri = URI("http://graph.facebook.com/#{@company.fbId}")
    data = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    @company.fbLikes= JSON.parse(data)['likes']
     @company.save!
   end
 end
```